# Is "Miss Clarke and the Computer" (1973) the first published song written from an intelligent machine's point of view?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computers, music

I just listened again to [Roy Wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Wood)'s 1973 album (recorded 1969-71) *Boulders* which at the time reached [critical acclaim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boulders_(album)#Critical_reception) for among other things its creativity, uniqueness and that:

> A reviewer for Stereo Review considered (it) likely be the first "one-man show" rock album "that really succeeds"

The [lyrics to "Miss Clarke and the Computer"](https://genius.com/Roy-wood-miss-clarke-and-the-computer-lyrics)

> I see why my, engineer came today
> Remove my screws, taken my heart away
> Why don't you touch me, press me,
> please, Miss Clarke
>
> I fail to solve problems efficiently
> Surely I know, you won't dismantle me
> Now press my switch, I'll play for you
> Please, Miss Clarke
>
> Can't she hear me, how can I ever say
> Please explain why, they programmed me this way
> I love you dearly, read me, please, Miss Clarke
>
> Systems failing, signal to you again (*sung more slowly*)
> I can't seem to function my inner brain
> Screwdrivers so sharp, now I'm scared, Miss Clarke
>
> Miss Clarke, Miss Clarke, don't take my heart awaaaayyyyy... (*played back at lower and lower speed *à la* Kubrick*)

I think that there are several artistic references to the iconic scene in Kubrick's 2001 A Space Odyssey where the HAL9001 computer is being shut down, saying "I can feel it, Dave" and then begins to sing *Daisy Bell*.

- [2001: A Space Odyssey's use of the song "Daisy Bell" (Bicycle Built for Two); life imitates art or vice-versa?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/209161/51174)

But the difference between that and

> Screwdrivers so sharp, now I'm scared

is that this is a new song, sung from the point of view of the computer being shut down, where it explains how this feels in the song's lyrics.

**note:** A warning for sentimental folks like me, the song is sad.

**Question:** Is "Miss Clarke and the Computer" (1973) the first published song written from an intelligent machine's point of view?

---

Comment: And take a listen at the wonderful [Saviour Machine](https://youtube.com/watch?v=U-AMec7yr7c) by David Bowie from his album *The Man Who Sold the World* from 1971: "*please don't believe in me, please disagree with me*"..

Comment: Just in case you were feeling too sad by the end, he does follow it, in true 'from the sublime to the ridiculous' manner by "When Grandma Plays the Banjo" ;)

Comment: Is it really intelligent? It can also be interpreted as anthropomorphizing the computer.

Comment: It's intelligent within the song's internal logic. Not only intelligent but in love.

Comment: By "protagonist" do you mean the the song is about an intelligent machine, or sung from an intelligent machine's point-of-view?

Comment: @fez ah, *an intelligent machine's point-of-view*. I've updated the title, how does that look?

Comment: A lot easier to understand now, thank you!

Comment: Clarification: are you looking only for machines whose intelligence is achieved via technology? Or does the scope include lower-tech machines that possess intelligence through sheer artistic license e.g. Lorne Greene's [I'm A Gun](https://genius.com/Lorne-greene-im-a-gun-lyrics)? Given people's fondness for anthropomorphising vehicles, toys, and weapons, that might be a fruitful direction for search, though I haven't yet found something that beats 1881.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent the intelligent machine has to actually be intelligent, and for the purposes of my question the intelligence has to have some element of plausibility viewed through the lens of science fiction. So robots and computers should qualify (there's no context in Miss Clarke and the Computer that indicates that it took place strictly within 1970's computer technology) and the anthropomorphizing of a gun (or the idea that it has feelings) should not qualify. But I don't know exactly how to draw a line in the middle that will work for everyone. We'll have to see how it goes...

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent *what an [interesting song](https://youtu.be/obg9IxGFxDY)!*

Comment: @uhoh Thanks, that saves me trawling through a bunch of stuff that might have fit the letter of the request but not the intention.

Comment: @uhoh Indeed. Perhaps I should've gone with [I'm A Train](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChgvPTVpbzs) instead, but the gun seemed a bit more of a thinker...

Answer (score 21):

**Earlier came OZ and its strange inhabitants:**

From the musical “[The Tik-Tok Man of Oz](https://oz.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tik-Tok_Man_of_Oz)”, 1913.
Words by L. Frank Baum.
Music by Louis F. Gottschalk.

[image: Original musical poster.]

<sup>Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike License 3.0 (Unported) ([CC BY-SA](https://www.fandom.com/licensing))</sup>

Link to [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSVERb4Waqg&embeds_referring_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sheetmusicsinger.com%2F&feature=emb_imp_woyt) of full song.

As to intelligence, he claims to "Show genius". You be the judge.

> I’m a man of many parts and complicated Clock work makes me go, Tik  Tok
> I can run because I’m finely regulated Never fast or slow, Tik Tok
> Right on time you’re always sure to find me
> If my works run down you musn’t mind me
> Take the key and then proceed to wind me
> And my genius I will show, Tik Tok

From [Sheetmusicsinger.com](https://www.sheetmusicsinger.com/the-clockwork-man/).

From the book, Tick-Tok of OZ. Portrayed in the Disney film Return to OZ:

[image: Image of man in suite, then still from film]

<sup>All rights Disney Pictures, fair use.</sup>

In-suit performance by Michael Sundin.

Comment: Big props to Michael Sundin, that suit looks incredibly uncomfortable!

Answer (score 10):

Les contes d'Hoffmann (The Tales of Hoffman), Jaques Offenbach, 1881.

In Act I, the poet Hoffman has fallen in love with the mechanical doll "Olympia" who sings one of the most famous coloratura arias in the repertoire before self-destructing.

The aria is: ["Les oiseaux dans la charmille" (The birds in the bower, often called "The Doll Song")](https://youtu.be/mVUpKIFHqZk).  In it, she sings about how the beauty of nature fills her "heart" with thoughts of love.

> Les oiseaux dans la charmille 
> Dans les cieux l'astre du jour, 
> Tout parle à  la jeune fille d'amour! 
> Ah! Voilà  la chanson gentille 
> La chanson d'Olympia! Ah!
>
> Tout ce qui chante et résonne 
> Et soupire, tour à  tour, 
> Emeut son coeur qui frissonne d'amour! 
> Ah! Voilà la chanson mignonne 
> La chanson d'Olympia! Ah!

**English translation:**

> The birds in the bower, 
> The day star in the heavens, 
> All speaks of love to the young girl!  
> Ah! This is the pleasant song,  
> The song of Olympia!  Ah!
>
> All that sings and resonates 
> And sighs, in turn 
> Moves her heart which quivers with love! 
> Ah!  This is the lovely song, 
> The song of Olympia!  Ah!